# Inequality Condition For Two Subspaces Of A Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am Currently Studying About Orthogonality Of Two Subspaces,

If two Subspaces $V$ And $W$ of dimensions $p$ and $q$ respectively of a vector space $R^n $ What can be an inequality condition for $p + q$ that guarantees that the 2 subspaces intersect in a nonzero vector.

I think a possible solution could be that $Rank(M)<n$, where $M$ is a matrix containing the basis vectors for the two subspaces

Is this solution valid? What other possible conditions could be considered?

Edit: The Solution I Posed Earlier is incorrect ,Please refer To the comment section to find the answers stated by @BenGrossmann

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are subspaces, then there is no notion of a "rank" of $V + W$

Comment: One condition that ensures that they have a non-trivial intersection is 
$$
\dim(V) + \dim(W) > n
$$

Comment: I should have clarified, that what I meant by rank was the rank of a matrix which contains the basis vectors for the two sub spaces, I shall edit it and clear it up

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank You For The Clarifications.

Comment: For your question as currently stated, $\operatorname{rank}(M) < p + q$ would be another such condition. The solution you suggest is incorrect